# Liferay 7.0 Facebook Integrations

Tags: liferay-7

I'm trying to integrate Facebook with Liferay. For that created app on facebook developers account. In app configuration for OAuth Redirect URI used 'https://abcde.com/' and configured all other necessary settings required (Reference : https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/sso-via-facebook). To increase the security, now facebook requires HTTPS for the handling of all Facebook Login access tokens, so I have added the certificate to site. Is any other way to do this integration?

I am using Liferay version : 7.0 GA3

Regards,
 Ashish.

Comment: Are you asking on how to do this without HTTPS? If not, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: yes i am asking how to do this without HTTPS. or any other any way to do this with http

Comment: [Don't crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site), or at least link the posts in all directions. [Same question in the Liferay Forums](https://community.liferay.com/en_GB/forums/-/message_boards/message/112247283).